# could you please help me to understand this sentence: "I just as soon leave it a mystery"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> fortuneteller: do you want to hear you fortune?
>
> oldman: at my age, there is really only one big surprise left, and **i just as soon leave it a mystery**

I heard it in avatar-the last airbender animation series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fortuneteller wants to predict the future of an old man. He's old, so he knows that the only thing left to know is his own death, and he'd rather not know anything about it.